# How to replace a string with another string in csv file using C++

Tags: c++, file

I am opening a csv file which contains entries in the form "key,value".
Task is to find a particular key and modify its corresponding value with another string. (key & value : both are strings).

```
int main() 

{   

    std::fstream m_file;
    m_file.open("input.csv", std::ios::in | std::ios::out);
    m_file << "Star,Treks\n";
    m_file << "Captain,America\n";
    m_file << "Black,Cats\n";   
    m_file << "Ninja,Fighters\n";

    std::string row;
    std::string key = "Black";
    std::string value = "Dreamers";
    while (std::getline(m_file, row)) {
        std::size_t pos = row.find(',');
        std::string retrieved_key = row.substr(0, pos);
        std::string retrieved_value = row.substr(pos + 1);
        if (retrieved_key == key) {
            std::size_t currentPos = m_file.tellg();
            std::size_t row_length = row.length();
            m_file.seekp(currentPos - row_length);
            std::string newEntry = key + "," + value + "\n";
            m_file << newEntry;
            return 0;
        }
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

This is the code I have written. But it does not work. It modifies the contents of the file as below :

> ```
> Star,Treks
> Captain,America
> BlBlack,Dreamers
> Fighters
> ```

Comment: "Cats" is not the same length as "Dreamers" so this method won't work. You could read the entire file into a vector or map, change whatever, then write the data back to the file.

Comment: If your requirement doesn't have to be C++, sed is a better tool for the job. Try: `sed -i 's/key,value/key,new_value/g' file`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify files directly using `seekg()` and `tellg()` functions unless these have a fixed size format of the parts you want to change.

The usual way to do such things is to create an intermediary temp file to write your changes, and replace the original one with it after you're done.

Answer (score -1):

Recipe:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

class pair : public std::pair<std::string, std::string>
{
public:
    using std::pair<std::string, std::string>::pair;
    bool operator==(pair const & rhs) const { return first == rhs.first; }

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &is, pair &p)
    {
        std::getline(is, p.first, ',');
        std::getline(is, p.second, '\n');
        return is;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, pair const &p)
    {
        os << p.first << ',' << p.second << '\n';
        return os;
    }
};

int main()
{
    char const *filename = "input.csv";
    std::fstream file{ filename, std::ios::in };
    if (!file) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open file \"" << filename << "\"!\n\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::vector<pair> data{
        std::istream_iterator<pair>{ file },
        std::istream_iterator<pair>{}
    };
    file.close();

    auto it{ std::find(data.begin(), data.end(), pair{ "Black", "" }) };
    if (it == data.end()) {
        std::cerr << "Key not found!\n\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    it->second = "Dreamers";

    file.open(filename, std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc);
    if (!file) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open file \"" << filename << "\"!\n\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    for (auto const & entry : data)
        file << entry;
}
```

Comment: This solution works. So, I will have to load entire content of the file in a container before making any changes to it

Comment: @user3370378 that's just \*one\* possible solution. You can also process each line on its own.

Comment: Yes I already did that..but the problem with that approach is if the contents of my new line are bigger than the contents of my old line, then it overrides the next line (example mentioned in the code above)